# How do I install the Firestorm viewer for Second Life?

Tags: software-installation

I am new to Ubuntu and trying to set everything up. I am VERY bad at doing that at the moment. In fact, I asked another question here only a few hours ago. Anyways, I am trying to get the Firestorm Viewer for Second Life. I followed instruction given here: http://michaelferrie.blogspot.com/2012_04_01_archive.html and came up with these end results:

```
cordenne@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
[sudo] password for cordenne: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree 
Reading state information... Done
ia32-libs is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libnspr4-0d:i386 libgconf2-4:i386 libnss3-1d:i386
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
cordenne@ubuntu:~$ '/home/cordenne/install.sh' 
You are not running as a privileged user, so you will only be able
to install the Firestorm Viewer in your home directory. If you
would like to install the Firestorm Viewer system-wide, please run
this script as the root user, or with the 'sudo' command.
Proceed with the installation? [Y/N]: Y
- Installing to /home/cordenne/firestorm
cp: cannot copy a directory, `/home/cordenne/firestorm', into itself, `/home/cordenne/firestorm/firestorm'
Failed
cordenne@ubuntu:~$ 
cordenne@ubuntu:~$
```

So, still no Firestorm. Can anyone help.

PS: When it said  - Installing to /home/cordenne/firestorm I felt it was talking to long to... I guess do anything so I pressed 'Enter'. I don't know if that made a difference but if it does, now you know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a firestorm Install, but only extract in a Folder, than run ./snowglobe

If you have a 64Bit Linux, use the "kokua viewer 64 Bit" from imprudence coders...
firestorm has Problems with Music Streaming...

http://blog.kokuaviewer.org/

and Download from: http://cdn.bitbucket.org/NickyP/kokua-dev/downloads/Kokua-3.3.3-Beta_1c-Linux64.tar.bz2

Greetings

Lupo

Answer (score 0):

To Install the latest SecondLife Firestorm Viewer For Ubuntu 14.04 LTS;

Once you download the Firestorm latest update compressed file from the firestorm web site, 'extract' the downloaded compressed folder from the “downloads” folder into your "User or Home” folder or desktop as you prefer.

If you wish to install Firestorm on your desktop menus;

Open a Terminal window, and navigate to the extracted folder.  Should look something like this:

“file:///home/YOURNAME/Phoenix_FirestormOS-Release_i686_4.6.7.42398”

run: the command, './etc/refresh_desktop_app_entry.sh' to install it from the command line in the terminal window.  NOTE: only include the syntax between the two  (') marks...

Then in this same terminal window, run  './firestorm' to launch “Firestorm viewer”

This should place the “Firestorm Icon” on your side bar.  If you wish to “pin” that program launch icon, now is the time to pin it.   To pin the Firestorm icon to the “Launcher” tool bar, right click, and choose to “Lock” the start up icon to that location.

Comment: You should learn how to format posts: http://askubuntu.com/editing-help